# Law of Cosines: positive or negative last term?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The law of cosines is usually stated something like

$$
C^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2 AB \cos \theta
$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle opposite C in our triangle.

However, if we have three vectors such that
$$
\vec{C} = \vec{A} + \vec{B}
$$
with $\theta$ being the angle between $ \vec{A}$ and $ \vec{B}$, we can easily take the dot product of $ \vec{C}\cdot\vec{C}$ to find that
$$
C^2 = A^2 + B^2 + 2 AB \cos \theta.
$$

Why are these so similar except for the different sign at the end? I can’t figure out why this wouldn’t give the exact same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Because these two $C$'s are different.The first one is
$$C_1^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2 AB \cos \theta$$
The second one is $\vec{C_2}=\vec{A}+\vec{B}$, thus
$$C_2^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2 AB \cos (180^\circ-\theta)= A^2 + B^2 + 2 AB \cos \theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at the drawing and notice that if $\vec{c}=\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ the angle $\theta$ is **NOT** the one between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as in the dot product, but rather the supplementary angle.

[image]